SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'processing.org_dress_id' in 'on clause' in CakePHP
$emp_detail = $this->fetchTable('EmpDetails')
                    ->find(contain: ['Processing.ProcessStage', 
                                    'Processing.OrgDress.PrimaryC',
                                    'Processing.OrgDress.SecondaryC', 
                                    'Processing.CutStock.ClothCutting.Items', 
                                    'Processing.CutStock.ClothCutting.ClothDetail', 
                                    'Processing.CutStock.ClothCutting.Orders.Organisation', 
                                    'Processing.CutStock.ClothCutting.Orders.OrderDetails'])
                    ->where(['EmpDetails.role_id IN' => array('4', '6', '7')])
                    ->join(['o' => ['table' => 'order_details', 
                                    'type' => 'LEFT', 
                                    'conditions' => 'o.org_dress_id = processing.org_dress_id']])
                    ->all()
                    ->toList();

this is my code for retrieving the result set for the EmpDetails Table. But for some reasons it is giving me above error. My tables look like this:



Table Name
Columns




emp_details
id, role_id, name


processing
id, emp_id, cut_stock_id, sq_str, org_dress_id


cut_stock
id, cloth_cutting_id, sq_str


cloth_cutting
id, emp_id, cloth_detail_id, item_id, order_id


orders
id, org_id


order_details
id, order_id, org_dress_id, sq_str



Now the column org_dress_id is in two tables processing and order_details.
org_dress_id column stores the information about the details of the product. org_dress_id in processing table stores which item is being produced. And org_dress_id in order_details  table stored if there is any order of the same product. Now when I retrieve the emp_details data using the above line of code I have put a left join so that it fetches only the orders for which the processing is being done. but it is throwing above error.
If I do not put the join it fetches all the order details related to the order_id but I do not want that.

I think you want Processing.org_dress_id, not processing.org_dress_id.

I've tried that but it still isn't working

Is the error message the same when you try it that way?
